# How to see what excatly is copied (in html code) when I copy from website content in Chrome or other modern browsers?

Tags: browser, operating-systems, html, copy-paste, clipboard

When I copy some text content from a website, I would assume the content is stored as html in clipboard since it tends to keep formats. And those htmls are different from the ones in page source (browsers may have appropriately edited a bit. E.g. browsers may inline the external referenced css in the web clip)

Is there a way to see what exactly those htmls are, in raw/un-rendered format?

I would like simple approaches in Ubuntu as well as in Windows.

Comment: paste into a text document...

Comment: Most browsers won't copy the html code in the case you describe.

Comment: If you paste into a text editor, no formatting is copied, but somehow formatting is retained when you paste into an office program: if you save it and examine the file you will see the office formatting, not what came from the clip-board. No idea how this works, but I'm as curious about the answer as you are. I hope someone can enlighten us.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you would like to see the RAW data (html code) that is copied to the clipboard in a scenario like this:

- You copy some block of text from a website
- When you paste into 'Word' it pastes it as rich text (colors, URLs, etc)

I cannot think of way to do this natively, though someone might be able to correct me.

You could try '[Clipboard Viewer](https://code.google.com/p/clipboardviewer/)'

This will show an HTML encoding of the data and more.